# how to integrate socket mobile scanner with android app and retrieve results

Tags: android, bluetooth, socketmobile, capture-sdk

I need to integrate socket mobile Bluetooth scanner on my android app.. i tried there SDK they prescribed in their site https://docs.socketmobile.com/capture/java/en/latest/getting-started.html
but its not getting the scanned result. and this is my activity.

class ScannerMobileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner_mobile)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


    Capture.builder(applicationContext)
        .enableLogging(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .build()


}


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onMessageEvent(event: DataEvent) {
    Log.i(TAG, event.data.string)
    //dataSourceView.text = event.data.dataSource.name
    textView2.text = event.data.string
}


    companion object {
        private val TAG : String = MainActivity::class.java.name
    }


public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
}

public override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

What version android are you using? if it is 9.0, this might be it: https://docs.socketmobile.com/capture/java/en/latest/android/getting-started.html#targeting-android-28